# range between two columns in R

Tags: r

I have a pretty straight forward question. I am trying to get the range between two columns for each row in R. I would like to score the range in a new column in the same data frame.

My data would look like:

```
x    y
107  233
87   123
95   284
261  287
```

I want to add a new column that has 107:233, 87:123, etc.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Just do `df$new <- do.call(paste, c(df, sep=":"))` if it is a string. but if we need a `list` column, then `df$new <- Map(":", df$x, df$y)`

Comment: @akrun why `do.call`? This works: `df$new <- paste(df$x,df$y,sep=":")`

Comment: @Masoud FOr general case, when there are 100 columns

Comment: @akrun makes sense.

Comment: @Masoud Note that this may not return what you want if x is ever greater than y. If x= 100 and y = 90 you'd get 100:90

Comment: @Mako212 Let the OP know about it. ;)

Comment: @akrun thank you df$new <- Map(":", df$x, df$y) is what I needed!

Comment: @Mako212 thanks for the heads up, in my data set, that is never the case.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `Map` to get the sequence based on corresponding elements of 'x' and 'y' and assign it to 'new' which will be a `list` column

```
df$new <- Map(":", df$x, df$y)
```